# Rails where method with any created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I've got a method like this:

```rb
def transfers(material, capacity, category, created_at)
  transfers_range = Transfer.first.created_at..Transfer.last.created_at if created_at.nil?
  Transfer.where(
    sender_dispensary_id: id,
    status: %i[dispatched released returned],
    capacity: capacity,
    material: material,
    created_at: created_at.nil? ? transfers_range : Time.given_month_range(created_at)
  ).or(
    Transfer.where(
      receiver_dispensary_id: id,
      status: %i[dispatched released returned],
      capacity: capacity,
      material_id: material,
      created_at: created_at.nil? ? transfers_range : Time.given_month_range(created_at)
    )
  )
end
```

It's working, but is there a way to avoid query for `transfer_range`? I mean... If `created_at == nil`, then this function should skip `created_at` column, like it was not included in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `created_at` is `nil` then `transfers_range` basically covers all transfers and therefore the condition is pointless and I simple would query by `created_at` in that case.

```
def transfers(material, capacity, category, created_at)
  transfers = Transfer
    .where(status: %i[dispatched released returned], capacity: capacity, material_id: material)
    .where('sender_dispensary_id = :id OR receiver_dispensary_id = :id', id: id)

  transfer = transfer.where(created_at: Time.given_month_range(created_at)) if created_at

  transfer
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `transfers_range` query can be avoided by breaking your query into multiple lines and adding a condition on `created_at` presence separately. You can also combine both the OR queries into a single query like this:

```
def transfers(material, capacity, category, created_at)
  transfer_data = Transfer.where('sender_dispensary_id = ? OR receiver_dispensary_id = ?', id).where(status: %i[dispatched released returned], capacity: capacity, material_id: material)
  transfer_data = transfer_data.where(created_at: Time.given_month_range(created_at)) if created_at.present?
  transfer_data
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consolidate the created_at query logic so it's in one place and you don't have to repeat it.

```
  created_at = if created_at.nil?
    Transfer.first.created_at..Transfer.last.created_at
  else
    Time.given_month_range(created_at)
  end
```

You also don't need to repeat the whole where condition twice. You want the equivalent of...

```
where status in ('dispatched', 'released', 'returned')
  and capacity = ?
  and material = ?
  and created_at = ?
  and (
    sender_dispensary_id = ?
    or
    receiver_dispensary_id = ?
  )
```

You do that like so:

```
  Transfer
    .where(
      status: %i[dispatched released returned],
      capacity: capacity,
      material: material,
      created_at: created_at
    )
    .where(
      Transfer
        .where(receiver_dispensary_id: id)
          .or(Transfer.where(sender_dispensary_id: id))
    )
  )
```

You can make this even more concise, and hide the details, by putting the logic into a [scopes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

```
class Transfer < Application
  scope :by_dispensary_id ->(id) {
    where(receiver_dispensary_id: id)
      .or(where(sender_dispensary_id: id))
  }

  scope :by_created_month ->(time) {
    if time.nil?
      where(created_at: first.created_at..last.created_at)
    else
      where(created_at: Time.given_month_range(time))
    end
  }
end
```

And now the query is much simpler.

```
  Transfer
    .by_dispensary_id(id)
    .by_created_month(created_at)
    .where(
      status: %i[dispatched released returned],
      capacity: capacity,
      material: material
    )
  )
```